# WCF RIA - Query operator 'Count' is not supported

Tags: c#, linq, wcf-ria-services, ria

I'm trying the following code..

```
LoadOperation<Tasks> PhasesLP = context.
    Load(context.GetTasksQuery().
    Where(o=> ProjectList.Where(p=> p.ProjectID == o.ProjectID).Count() == 1)
```

I get the following error:

> Query operator 'Count' is not supported.

I want to basically be able to specify a `Where In` clause instead of `Where =`.

Anyone has an idea of how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
.SingleOrDefault() != null
```

I'm not familiar with RIA, but sometimes these kinds of alternate equivalent expressions work with EF.

Also, with EF, it's possible to do a SQL-style `WHERE IN (...)` using `.Any(...)`.

Off the top of my head, this kind of thing works:

```
entities.Where(e => ids.Any(i => e.Id == i))
```

`ids` may be a list of IDs, another list of entities or a subquery, IIRC.